# File in a folder are not being cycled through with for loop

Tags: php, xml

When I attempt to loop through my for loop that looks like this :

```
$singleArray = array_column($upcValuesFromArray, count($upcValuesFromArray));
$groupedArrays = array_chunk($singleArray, 5, false); 

for($i = 0; $i < count($groupedArrays); $i++){
    $xmlFilePath = 'xml/' . $file_name . $i . '.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFilePath);
    echo $xmlFilePath;
foreach($xml->children() as $items) { 
     //Pull UPC data
    echo $items['Id'] . ',';

    //Verify complete listing
    if (isset($items->Products->Product->SalesRankings->SalesRank[0]->Rank) == false) {
        //Pull ASIN data
        echo $items->Products->Product->Identifiers->MarketplaceASIN->ASIN . ',';
        //Pull pricing data
        echo $items->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount . ',';


        continue;
    } 
    //Pull sales rank data
    echo $items->Products->Product->SalesRankings->SalesRank[0]->Rank . ',';
    //Pull pricing data
    echo $items->Products->Product->AttributeSets->children('ns2', true)->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->Amount . ',';
}
}
```

I get all of the data, but only for one file. I am not sure what i am doing wrong. If someone could help me, i would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you in advance! I appreciate the help.

Comment: What does `$groupedArrays` contain?

Comment: $groupedArrays is the arrays of the arrays.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `$groupedArrays` might contain only 1 value explaining why it only iterates once through the first loop.

When you call: `array_chunk($singleArray, 5, false);` that should be returning an array of array(s) if that makes sense.

So the resulting array would look something like:

```
array(
    0 => array(
       0 => 0, 
       1 => 1, 
       2 => 2,
    )
)
```

Yet you are expecting something like:

```
array(
    0 => 0, 
    1 => 1, 
    2 => 2,
)
```

I am not entirely sure that `array_chunk` is required here at all.

I would first output your `$groupedArrays` by calling `print_r($groupedArrays);` right after you create that array and see what is actually there.

---

In order to get 3 arrays, try calling `array_chunk` like this:

```
$groupedArrays = array_chunk($singleArray, 1, false);
```

This should result in something like:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 0, 
    ),   
    1 => array( 
        0 => 1, 
    ),
    2 => array(
        0 => 2,
    )
)
```

That will now work with your loop to iterate through 3 files as expected, however this seems overly complex for your task.

Comment: $groupedArrays is the value of how many files we have, but i will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, so $groupedArrays is not an array but an integer? In that case just remove the `count()` in your for loop.

Comment: doesn't it have to count the number of files. i will post more of my code in the question.

Comment: $groupedArrays contains all 3 values. array_chunk is needed to get the values of $singleArray into 1 array. $singleArray has 11 values. $groupedArrays chunks it into 3 arrays. so, i am not sure exactly where you are going with this. the output is the first example that you provided and was exactly what i was expecting.

Comment: Well, then your initial loop will not work at all. If you wanted 3 arrays, call `array_chunk` with `1` as the 2nd parameter. I will update the answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Sorry, i fixed it. I will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There was a problem with the simplemxl values. ie:

```
$items->Products->Product->SalesRankings->SalesRank[0]->Rank
```

This didn't exist in some of the xml files.

Thanks.